# org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for firstname in class com.hibernate.demo.user

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I already write getter method for firstname variable but it again throw a exception. Please tell me how to handle this. I already did google but in those solutions always line missing but in my case I already define setter getter methods.

```
package com.hibernate.demo;

public class user 
{
    private int id;
    private String firstname, lastname;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstname)
    {
        this.firstname=firstname;
    }
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastname)
    {
        this.lastname=lastname;
    }
}
```

property file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.hibernate.demo.user" table="users">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstname">
            <column name="firstname"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lastname">
            <column name="lastname"/>
        </property>
</class>
```

Comment: Exactly what line is the exception thrown on and what is the message?

Answer (score 0):

Your property is called `firstname` so getter method should be called `getFirstname()`, not `getFirstName()`. The same situation is with `lastname`.